# Are the input and output tensors of a torch.fx.Node object accessible?

Tags: pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and machine learning in general, so please excuse if the following is obvious...Given an individual `torch.fx.node.Node` object from a `torch.fx.graph.Graph`, are the input and output tensors of the node accessible so they may be examined or dumped?  If I print the graph object, I can see the input arguments:

`%slice_1 : [num_users=1] = call_function[target=torch.ops.aten.slice.Tensor](args = (%arg1_1, 0, 0, 2468000000), kwargs = {})`

`%slice_2 : [num_users=1] = call_function[target=torch.ops.aten.slice.Tensor](args = (%slice_1, 1, 0, 384), kwargs = {})`

Presumably the input tensors to `slice_1` are the placeholder `arg199_1` and three fixed constants.  How do I access the tensor values for `arg199_1`?  Similarly, the inputs for `slice_2` are the output from `slice_1` and three fixed constants.  Can the tensor values for the output of `slice_1` be accessed?

I've been searching but have not come up with any solution - does a correlation to a `torch.fx.node` and it's input/output tensors exist?